# Korn Shell pattern detection and deletion

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I am working with Korn Shell to try and detect error messages in a flat file that aren't needed. The flat file has multiple error records, where certain ones can be deleted and others need to be kept. Errors like:

> Message: TR0405 Severity: 04
> Application data received will be ignored.
> blah blah blah.

Need to be deleted, while a message with any other code needs to be kept in. I'm having trouble deleting this record, while keeping the next record fully intact. I want to delete from the detected pattern

> Message: TR0405 Severity: 04

To the next detected pattern of just

> Message:

My current code:

```
sed -e "/Message: TR0405 Severity: 04/,/Message:/{//p;d;}" test.txt > newTest.txt
  rm test.txt
  mv newTest.txt test.txt
```

Example of data:

> Message: TR0405 Severity: 04
>
> Application data received will be ignored.
>
> blah blah blah.
>
> Message: TR0405 Severity: 04
>
> Application data received will be ignored.
>
> blah blah blah.
>
> Message: TR0405 Severity: 04
>
> Application data received will be ignored.
>
> blah blah blah.
>
> More blah blah blah.
>
> Message: TR0425 Severity: 04
>
> Error with timing.
>
> blah blah blah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like : ( EDITED to account to the new example)

```
#!/bin/ksh

Logfile=$1

while read line; do
    if [[ $line == Message* ]]; then
        flag=0
        case $line in
            *TR0405*)       continue
                            ;;
            "")     continue
                    ;;
            *)      print $line >> logresult.txt
                    flag=1
                    ;;
        esac
    elif [[ $flag -eq 1 ]]; then
        print $line >> logresult.txt
    fi
done < $Logfile
```

You can add any error code in the case statement. With you example of data it works well.

Comment: The error report can occur over multiple lines, how would I account for this?

Comment: You should always give meaningful example of data. Can you provide a real example ?

Comment: Okay, I edited the example in the question to better reflect what I have.

Comment: Probably `print -r -- "$line"` not just `print $line` though…